# Is there a way for a user to disable an AlertDialog completely?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

In the app I'm making, I have an "if" statement where if two strings are saved to a certain string, an AlertDialog pops up. These strings will stay the same for some users, thus having this AlertDialog constantly pop up whenever they launch the activity where the ALertDialog is set to appear. Code (I have no setNegativeButton as of yet):

```
 private void SetWarning() {

    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    alert.setTitle("Warning!");
    alert.setMessage(R.string.Warning);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        //No action needed; just close the AlertDialog.
            }
        });

alert.show(); }
```

Here is a segment of my code that makes this AlertDialog appear:

```
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String s = sharedPreferences2.getString("MEM1", "");
        String s2 = sharedPreferences2.getString("MEM2", "");

    if(s.equals("String1") && s2.equals("String2"))
        SetWarning();
```

Is there a way to make an "alert.setNegativeButton" method where if the user clicks it, the AlertDialog will NEVER appear again? I'm thinking of maybe somehow implementing another SavedPreferences somehow so it saves the users selection and will then prevent the AlertDialog from ever appearing again. So far, to no luck. I've searched to find nothing, other than people asking how to disable buttons in an AlertDialog.

Thank you!

New updated code:

```
        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //set sharedpreferences boolean called DONTSHOWAGAIN to true;
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Boolean dontShowAgain = sharedPreferences2.getBoolean("dontShowAgain ", false);
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sharedPreferences2.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("dontShowAgain", true);
            ed.commit();
        }
    });

alert.show(); } 

private void StringWarning() {



        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String s = sharedPreferences2.getString("MEM1", "");
        String s2 = sharedPreferences2.getString("MEM2", "");


    if(s.equals("String1") && s2.equals("String2")){
        if(!dontShowAgain){
            SetWarningExamConflict();
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is, attach "setNegativeButton" and handle the click:

```
alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
        //set sharedpreferences boolean called DONTSHOWAGAIN to true;
    }
});
```

and then, alter your AlertDialog invocation:

```
Boolean dontShowAgain = sharedPreferences2.getBoolean("DONTSHOWAGAIN", false);

if(s.equals("String1") && s2.equals("String2")){
    if(!dontShowAgain){
        SetWarning();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm having issues with it at the moment. I'll definitely not forget to hit the Best Answer check mark though!

Comment: please see that I changed `getString` to `getBoolean`. Typo on my side.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! It fixed every issue! Time to test it out :)

Comment: Got it working. Thanks! It really is appreciated that you take the time to help out. Thanks again!